# Kähler differentials, define valuation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208418/intuition-for-thinking-about-r-module-of-k%C3%A4hler-differentials-universal-recep) for a definition of the $R$-module of Kähler differential $\Omega_{R/k}$.

Suppose $k$ is a field of characteristic $0$, $R$ is a $k$-algebra, and let $K$ be a finite extension of $k(x)$. If $[K: k(x)] < \infty$ and $\omega \in \Omega_{R/k}$, then we define $v_R(\omega) = v_R(f)$, where $\omega = f\,dt$ for some uniformizing parameter $t$, and $v$ is the associated valuation.

It is easy to check that this is independent of choice of uniformizing parameter for a given discrete valuation ring. If $t'$ is another choice of uniformizing parameter, then $R\,dt = R\,dt'$, which implies that $dt = u\,dt'$ for some $u \in R$ and $dt' = v\,dt$ for some $v \in R$. Then $uv = 1$, so $u$ and $v$ are units.

My question is, what is the correct way to think about/visualize this definition of valuation and unpack all the formalism? Preferably in context of algebraic curves?

Comment: Possibly dumb questions: what do $R$ and $K$ have to do with one another? From where are you getting a uniformizer? Is there some DVR floating around?

Comment: Now posted to MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/q/208443

Comment: I guess you mean that $R$ is a DVR, so in particular integral. In this case the module of Kahler differentials is trivial, so you can define a valuation on it after choosing some embedding $H^0(X, \Omega_X) \to k(X)$ where $X = \mathrm{Spec} R$, which is tantamount to picking a trivialization. There is no canonical trivialization, but all the valuations obtained this way will be the same since all trivializing sections do not vanish anywhere.